# functional derivative of an integral of the function itself

Tags: calculus, functional-equations, derivatives

I have the following

$$
\frac{d}{dn(x)} \int_{x \in \cal{R}^3} {n(x) dx}
$$

I know that this additional relationship holds

$$
\int_{x \in \cal{R}^3}{n(x) dx} = N
$$

where N is a constant.

My question is, what is the value of the above derivative, and what is the procedure for this case? I am not really experienced in functionals and functional derivatives.

Comment: As written the "additional relationship" is nonsense. An indefinite integral is a set of functions often written in the form "$\ N(x)+C\ $" and cannot be equal to "a constant" $N$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter : ok sorry. The integration is over the 3D space.

Comment: @StefanoBorini I think that $\frac{d}{dn(x)}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}n(x)dx=\frac{dN}{dn(x)}=0$.